# How do I remove a "hidden" class in 1 instance using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking for quick help. Don't want to get into the background of this project but can you tell me if this is formatted right? It doesn't seem to be working.

```
"Hello" === a.title ? (r.html(r.removeClass("hidden")), "fr" === pageLang && r.html(r.removeClass("hidden")));
```

My HTML has this:

```
Hello. < span class="hide-this hidden" >Goodbye< / span > Mr. Burns
```

I added these in my json.

```
r = $(".hide-this");

"Hello" === a.title ? (r.html(r.removeClass("hidden")), "fr" === pageLang && r.html(r.removeClass("hidden")));
```

Don't mind the language toggle rules, they work. The issue I am having is the removeClass. I can get it to work globally, but I want it to work only when the title is Hello. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you confusing JSON with jQuery???

Comment: WTH is that `r.html()` call?

Comment: You've got a syntax error: You only have `?` but no `:` in your conditional expression. Please post the actual code.

Comment: What a ternary test. I'd rather not be the next dev debugging this one.

Comment: jquery for sure. sorry. I forgot that I converted the json to .js.. to make it easier, I just want to remove the hidden class in one instance when the content is used globally.

Comment: ok, so fixed the syntax. wrote it out like: 

"Hello" === a.title ? (r.html(r.removeClass("hidden")), "fr" === pageLang && r.html(r.removeClass

("hidden"))) : (r.html(r.addClass("hidden")), "fr" === pageLang && r.html(r.addClass("hidden")));


The action I am getting now is the Hidden class and the actual Goodbye gets removed from the html when I call that title. Almost there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure you need the `r.html()` blocks inside of your code. Also, inline if's are generally a bad place to have functionality, as it is stylistically unclear what is going on.

```
r = $( '.hide-this' );
if( a.title == "Hello" ) {
    r.removeClass( "hidden" );
}
```

I am unsure what you are looking to happen in the second portion of that line. [jQuery's html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) accepts 0 or 1 argument, not 2. What are you trying to accomplish by passing it a second argument?

Edit: Additionally, as a sanity check, make sure that the `css` of your `.hide-this` does not include a `display: none;` line, as that would make removing the `.hidden` ineffective.

Comment: hey Ben

there is actually no CSS for the display. The idea is I added the class to the html and add hidden.. I control it from the js. Now I addressed the syntax error and it is almost working. Only thing is it is not only removing the hidden class it is also removing the actual work so it is coming out like < span class="hide-this >< / span >

Comment: Do you still have the `r.html()` in there? I don't see why you would need it. It sets the inner html of the element, but you just want to remove the class. By having it there, you are passing it a boolean, thus clearing the span's content.

Comment: Ben, that makes sense, thanks for clarifying that. The code worked.

Thanks pal!